# CS:GO Servers information

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Let's say I have a server on my own. I have users who play there. Casual game. Best 8 of 15. Is there a way I could get the information about every game that ends? Eg.

- CT / T won;
- Rounds won by the winning side;
- Accuracy level of the players;
- K/D/A statistics per player;
- Or other kinds of statistics is more than welcomed.

I'm just asking if the servers provide this information, not looking for a particular software that does that. But if you know about something like this, I'd be more than happy to see it.

Answer (score 4):

What you need are Server queries to recieve information from a running server.
To work with queries you should have some develop-understanding because most of the query example around the net are written in php.

There's a documentation about it on the [Valve Developer page](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Server_queries).

After that you should start to read about the [RCON Protocol](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_RCON_Protocol).

[Here're](https://www.gametracker.com/games/csgo/forum.php?thread=91691) some things you can (de-)activate in the server.cfg.

**Update:**

I've found [a open source library](https://github.com/xPaw/PHP-Source-Query-Class) for php which make the things a bit easier.

Answer (score 1):

The RCON protocol won't get you where you want to be, really.  It allows you to query for the current status (ie, the number of people connected, map, score, teams, etc) but for any real statistics you're going to want to check the log file.

There are console/config commands that allow the log to be transmitted over UDP as well as written to disk, so knowledge of RCON can be important depending on what your goals are.

The log file standard is documented [on the Valve developer Wiki](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/HL_Log_Standard).  You can write an offline or realtime parser for the log, which can allow you to collect all sorts of interesting statistics.

There are also "SuperLog" plugins for most Source engine games which will augment the default log options and give you more info than you'd normally have.  See [this thread](https://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?t=204510) for more info.

As you may imagine, this is actually a popular thing, so several stats programs exist already.  The one I'm most familiar with is [HLX:CE](https://forums.alliedmods.net/forumdisplay.php?f=156) since I've contributed to the source in the past.  From what I recall, setting it up requires some technical know-how, but it's free.

If you don't mind paying $5/month, you might check out [gameME](https://www.gameme.com/) which is a popular paid alternative.  The money you invest in it is offset by the more "hands off" approach to the software.

Comment: Good one, didn't think about the log but you're right that would be exactly fit his needs